# Does "is designed" vs "was designed" imply anything different?

Tags: tense

A product has already been put into mass market,we can buy it everywhere,so,when I want to write an introduction for this product,should I use

XXX is designed to do sth.

or

XXX was designed to do sth.

Does this two have different meanings?If not, which one will be better?

Comment: For your exact context, it really makes no difference to the meaning, and neither version is "better" than the other. In other contexts *("Thumbscrews **were** designed to inflict maximum pain without causing death", "This product we're working on **is** designed to appeal to everyone")* the normal relevance of verb tense applies.

Comment: Why doesn't use Thumbscrews are designed to inflict maximum pain...What's the difference?Thanks

Comment: "Thumbscrews **are** designed ..." implies that they are still in use. Since torture is frowned on these days we should use past tense.

Answer (score 3):

As FumbleFingers said there is no difference in meaning. Consistency of verb tense and the implied usage is all that matters.

#### Trying to sell a product

> "This product we're working on is designed to appeal to everyone"
>
> "The WaveTek Washer is designed to do your laundry in half the time with half the water!"
>
> "The element of an electric oven is designed to produce 3.3kW of heat when connected to a 240-V source"

Using the present tense puts emphasis on the product being new and desirable. "Is designed" is most commonly heard in descriptions of function or purpose.

#### Talking about a product

> Thumbscrews were designed to inflict maximum pain without causing death"
>
> A: "Why didn't your phone break when you fell in the lake?"
> B: "My phone was designed to be waterproof."
>
> "Classical music was designed to share the composers emotion with the world"

The past tense here is suitable since both speakers are talking about the past: both the dropping of the phone and the design obviously occurred in the past. "Was designed" is most commonly heard when talking about a product.

Comment: Your various choice of phrasings *(implies, puts emphasis on, is suitable, etc)* implies an important point which doesn't seem to be explicitly made anywhere on this page. Either tense *can* be used in practically every context, apart from those where the "designed thing" is no longer meaningfully in use. And even then you *could* use present tense to heighten the "immediacy" of your point - [*"The medieval broadsword is designed to be swung so that the blow could penetrate heavy armor"*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22broadsword+is+designed%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl)